# I am doing an LSTM classification for DDoS detection. I have an error while performing the evaluation

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, confusion-matrix

This is the code that I have used. Now I do not really know where did I go wrong as I am new to such things. As an overview of what I am trying to do is that I am trying to classify where there is an attack or no. I gave 'Y' as my label that contains '11' classes.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data /Ecobee_Thermostat.csv')
#imports 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, 
f1_score
#label encoder 
data['Y'].unique() 
from sklearn import preprocessing 
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
data['Y']=label_encoder.fit_transform(data['Y'])
data['Y'].unique()
#ex
data.head(10)
data.isnull().sum()
data.shape
for col in data.columns:
    print(col)
x = data.iloc[:, 0:115]
x.shape
Y=data['Y']
Y
#scaling 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(x)
X= scaler.transform(x)
#split 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=44, shuffle =True)
#reshape 
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],1,X.shape[1]))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],1,X.shape[1]))
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
opt = keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(1,115),activation="relu",return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 5,batch_size=2000
, validation_data= (x_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)
print(score)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_predtrain = model.predict(x_train) (* here where I get the error) 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusiontr = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred)
confusionts = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred.round())
print('Confusion Matrix\n')
print(confusionts)
sn.heatmap(confusiontr)
```

When i do run it, it goes very well until evaluating the output be as followed:

```
> 0.8152588605880737
0.36209338903427124
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-61331f357bd6> in <module>()
      5 y_predtrain = model.predict(x_train)
      6 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
----> 7 confusiontr = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred)
      8 confusionts = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred.round())
      9 print('Confusion Matrix\n')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

   ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [560036, 275840]
```

this is a snapshot of the error
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp2F3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the following lines:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusiontr = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred)
```

Your `y_pred` comes from `x_test`, while your `y_train` comes from `x_train`. That is, your train and test sets have different dimensions, hence what you call `y_train` and `y_pred` on the last line above won't match either.

Thus, simply use `y_predtrain` instead for `confusiontr`:

```py
confusiontr = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_predtrain)
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to solve it ? It is my first project and i do not really know much

Comment: I did and I got this error  ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and unknown targets